# How can I fix my layout to look like this?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am having an issue with nesting my Swing Layout, I need to create the following layout as pictured.

**Left** - 4 Buttons

**Middle** - JMenu Bar and 2 JLabels

**Right** panel - 4 Buttons

The two side panels work fine for me but I can't get the middle piece working. I have tried using a Borderlayout here but I can only put 1 item NORTH (The JMenu) and 1 item CENTER (1st JLabel). I thought maybe I could subdivide the CENTRE with another JPane but it wouldn't work correctly.

I have also tried set the middle piece to Grid Layout but of course all elements get set to the same size so that won't do either.

**This is what I want it to look like**

[image]

**Code**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

class Test102 extends JFrame
{
    private JMenuBar menuTop;
    private JMenu fileMenu;

    public Test102() throws IOException
    {

        //Create 3 new Jpanels
        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        JPanel center = new JPanel();
        JPanel centerSubdivision1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel centerSubdivision2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel centerSubdivision3 = new JPanel();
        JPanel right = new JPanel();


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Create a grid layout - This will go to the left
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        left.setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 4, 1 ) );  //4 Rows and 1 Columns
        //Button 1
        left.add ( new JButton ( "Button 1" ) );
        //Button 2
        left.add ( new JButton ( "Button 2" ) );
        //Button 3
        left.add ( new JButton ( "Button 3" ) );
        //Button 4
        left.add ( new JButton ( "Button 4" ) );

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Create a grid layout - This will go in the middle.
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        center.setLayout ( new GridLayout( 4, 1) );

        //Top Menu Bar
        menuTop = new JMenuBar();
        center.add ( menuTop );

            //Top level menu
            fileMenu = new JMenu ( "File Menu", true );
            menuTop.add ( fileMenu ); //Add menu

            ///////////////////////////////////
            //Add another panel to the Centre
            ///////////////////////////////////
            center.add ( ( centerSubdivision1 ) );
            centerSubdivision1.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 0));

            center.add ( ( centerSubdivision2 ) );
            centerSubdivision2.setBackground(new Color(192, 0, 192));
                JLabel label1 = new JLabel ( "Label 1" );
                centerSubdivision2.add ( label1 );

            center.add ( ( centerSubdivision3 ) );
            centerSubdivision3.setBackground(new Color(0, 192, 192));
                JLabel label2 = new JLabel ( "Label 2" );
                centerSubdivision2.add ( label2 );

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Create a grid layout - This will go to the right
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        right.setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 4, 1 ) ); //4 Rows and 1 Columns
        //Button 5
        right.add ( new JButton ( "Button 5" ) );
        //Button 6
        right.add ( new JButton ( "Button 6" ) );
        //Button 7
        right.add ( new JButton ( "Button 7" ) );
        //Button 8
        right.add ( new JButton ( "Button 8" ) );

        //Add our Jpanels to the content pane.
        getContentPane().add ( left, BorderLayout.WEST );
        getContentPane().add ( center, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        getContentPane().add ( right, BorderLayout.EAST );

        //Set window parameters
        setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setTitle ( "Test Application" );
        setSize ( 800,600 );
        setVisible ( true );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        new Test102();
    }//End main
}//End Class
```

Comment: So how the labels should be positioned?

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes the MenuBar and JLabels, essentially I can't get the center piece working at all,  I can set the middle to BorderLayout and put the JMenu NORTH and 1 JLabel in the CENTER but I need a Jmenu and 2 labels in the middle.

Comment: I asked, how the labels should be possitioned, not left and right button bars, because I still dont know that. I only see how it looks right now, but dont know how it supposed to look like,.

Comment: @Antoniossss Oh right, no, no the pictures shows what it should look like!

Comment: Add a new JPanel in the center and add the labels to that

Comment: If you get familiar with GridBagLayout, you will be able to do anything ;) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: (1-) Don't reinvent the wheel. Companies spend millions of dollars to develop a consistent LAF. The menubar should be placed across the entire top of the frame. There is even a special method,`setJMenuBar`(...) on the frame to allow you to do this.

Comment: @camickr This is a modification of an original design, I am only just learning Swing so I am not sure of best practice.

Comment: `I am only just learning Swing` - it has nothing to do with Swing. Look at your computer. Look at the applications on your computer. They have a title bar. They have a menu bar. They have a tool bar. Learn by example. `I am not sure of best practice.` - you do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My purpose with this answer is to show an example of how you can get close to your desired layout. As @camickr states above:

> The menubar should be placed across the entire top of the frame. There
>   is even a special method,setJMenuBar(...) on the frame to allow you to
>   do this.

I think we *all* can *fully* support this statement.

**Original Answer**

Use a `BorderLayout` for your `CENTER` panel, placing the `JMenuBar` on `BorderLayout.NORTH`, a subpanel holding the labels will be placed on `BorderLayout.CENTER`.
That subpanel could have a `GridBagLayout` to automatically align the labels at the center of the panel.

[image]

You can use `GridBagConstraints.insets` to insert some blank space between the labels, in the code below i use 5 pixels for `insets.top`.

Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String [] a) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable () {
            @Override public void run () {
                createAndShowGUI ();
            }
        });
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Test Application");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane (new MainPanel ());

        // This instruction is used for convenience to let you see the final result, use pack () on your application.
        frame.setSize (800, 600);  
        // frame.pack ();

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
class MainPanel extends JPanel
{
    public MainPanel () {
        super (new BorderLayout ());

        JPanel left = new JPanel (new GridLayout (4, 1));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i ++) left.add (new JButton ("Button " + i));

        JPanel center = new JPanel (new BorderLayout ());

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar ();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu ("File Menu", true);
        menuBar.add (fileMenu);
        center.add (menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel labelsPanel = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout ());
        labelsPanel.add (new JLabel ("Label 1"));

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints ();
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets (5, 0, 0, 0);
        labelsPanel.add (new JLabel ("Label 2"), c);

        center.add (labelsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel right = new JPanel (new GridLayout (4, 1));
        for (int i = 5; i <= 8; i ++) right.add (new JButton ("Button " + i));

        add (left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add (center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add (right, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a vertical BoxLayout in the center JPanel.

```
BoxLayout bx = new BoxLayout();
bx.setAxis(JBoxLayout.VERTICAL);
center.setLayout(bx);
```